# Taylor expansion/approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I was given

$f(x) = x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}$

I was first asked to get the chebyshev expansion between $[-1,1]$ i did that part.

Now i have to get the taylor expansion i am not sure how to do this because taylor expansion is at one point like

$x = x_a$

and then you can use the standard formula.

But now that i have been given a range $[-1,1]$ what would i do? i could potentially just use $-1$ but that would be only that point...

I am a bit confused.

Comment: Do it around $0$.

Comment: @Andrei can i ask why?

Comment: The only Taylor series expansion valid throughout $[-1,1]$ is that around $0$ because the radius of convergence would be $1$.

Comment: Taylor expansion is similar to Chebyshev expansion. Just that the basis is now $1$, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1-a}$ for $a<1$,

$$\sqrt{1-a}=1-\frac a2 - \frac {a^2}{8} - \frac {a^3}{16} ...$$

and let $a=x^2$,

$$\sqrt{1-x^2}=1-\frac {x^2}{2} - \frac {x^4}{8} - \frac {x^6}{16} ...$$

Then,

$$f(x) = x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2} = x^2-\frac {x^4}{2} - \frac {x^6}{8} - \frac {x^8}{16} ...$$

Comment: wow, thanks i didn't even ask that as my question but would have been my next question. i figured that 0 is the point from the comment, but then i tried the question and it looked impossible with all this differentation. thanks a lot.

Comment: one more question for the denominators 2,8,16 how do you calculate that, i tried to search this $sqrt(1-x^2)$ but nothing is showing... im trying to get order 4,5,6

Comment: @Questions - 2,8,16... are derived from the derivatives of $y=\sqrt{x}$ at $x=1$, along with the Taylor expansion coefficients, 1/2, 1/6, 1/24...